# Slow Samba multitasking

Tags: linux, samba, network-share

I've setup a Debian 9 fileserver with Samba. When transferring data in LAN, I get a speed of approx 95Mbps which is alright but when I navigate through my folders while transferring they won't load and even crashing my explorer sometimes. When copying two files (different threads) the speed is equally distributed between both. Looks like Samba isn't able to balance the copying and browsing at the same time.

I'm wondering if this is normal behaviour, because in big industries, this would be a huge problem. Maybe there's a better alternative than Samba? It's important to know I'm using a Windows laptop and I want the shares to be in my native explorer.

The Samba config is below. Thanks in advance!

---

```
[global]
    obey pam restrictions = yes
    restrict anonymous = 2
    max log size = 1000
    socket options = TCP_NODELAY
    log file = /var/log/samba/samba.log
    server string = TurnKey FileServer
    pam password change = yes
    admin users = root
    recycle:touch = yes
    rpc_server:spoolss = external
    os level = 20
    netbios name = FILESERVER
    panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
    recycle:versions = yes
    encrypt passwords = true
    add user to group script = /usr/sbin/usermod -G '%g' '%u'
    passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
    passdb backend = tdbsam
    security = user
    printing = cups
    rpc_daemon:spoolssd = fork
    add user script = /usr/sbin/useradd -m '%u' -g users -G users
    unix password sync = yes
    guest account = nobody
    passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
    delete user script = /usr/sbin/userdel -r '%u'
    add group script = /usr/sbin/groupadd '%g'
    dns proxy = no
    syslog = 0
    wins support = true
    delete group script = /usr/sbin/groupdel '%g'
    load printers = yes
    vfs object = recycle
    recycle:keeptree = yes
    recycle:exclude_dir = tmp quarantine
    workgroup = WORKGROUP

[homes]
    valid users = %S
    browseable = no
    comment = Home Directory
    available = no
    writable = yes

[cdrom]
    available = no
    writable = no
    preexec = /bin/mount /media/cdrom
    locking = no
    postexec = /bin/umount /media/cdrom
    path = /media/cdrom
    comment = CD-ROM
    guest ok = yes

[mount]
    writeable = yes
    create mode = 775
    valid users = @users
    path = /mnt/diskdata/Werkschijf
    directory mode = 775
```

Comment: You didn't describe your system hardware-wise. Browsing the share requires IOPS, while transferring large files requires throughput. If you're sharing a single hard drive, it will be slow because the hard drive is slow. There's nothing that samba can do here.

Comment: I'm sharing a mounted hard drive through my proxmox system. If Samba can't speed up the process, is it beter to make a SSD cache drive or something?

Comment: You don't provide enough information. You're sharing a single hard drive, is it a USB drive? What's the filesystem on it? Why did you choose the oldstable Debian 9 instead of the stable 10? Plus I see you inserted socket options in your smb.conf. That's almost always a bad idea, it's the sort of advice that was useful more than 10 years ago but causes more trouble than it's worth. Are there many files on your hard drive? Often when the files are images the Windows explorer tries to create thumbnails and that slows everything down.

Comment: The hard drive is an internal SATA drive, ext4 in an LVM. It's an outdated server which will be upgraded soon to Debian 10. The socket option is recommended at many forums and that's why I inserted it too. The disk stores more than 300 000 files in which approx. 4000 images, movies and documents. I recently decided to change to ZFS for rendundancy so maybe this new setup will perform better. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Your disk contains lots of files and is very slow. The file explorer trying to read informations from many files at a time slows your disk to a crawl, there's nothing Samba can do about this.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much!